# A curious odd one out

Tags: pattern, lateral-thinking, odd-one-out

Which one of (a), (b), (c), (d) or (e) is the odd one out and why?

[image: odd one out]

<sup>Source: based on a puzzle from Alex Bellos</sup>

Comment: Who downvoted? This is not bad for a small puzzle, in my opinion.

Comment: @oAlt (Not me, but) we had a puzzle very similar to this, in that it had the same not-the-odd-one-out premise, not that long ago (a few weeks maybe?). I cannot find it now, it may have been deleted, but I recall it got a lot of flack, there was much discussion/debate in comments, and it garnered some downvotes. I wouldn't be surprised if this had a similar reception to some degree...

Comment: @stiv if you find that post please share a link here. I searched before posting but as you imagine it is difficult to find a duplicate of this one

Comment: @Stiv I see. (Why do I not remember that puzzle?) Anyway, in the long run, I cannot force someone to change their opinion on a particular puzzle. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm thinking it is

> (c)

since

> it itself is not an odd-one-out answer, though ironically, that makes it an odd-one-out as well. But hear me out on this one.
>
>  (a) is the only red number.
>  (b) is the only smaller-than-normal number.
>  (d) is the only number missing a segment.
>  (e) is the only one without a middle black segment.

I still don't know how to explain the title, though.

Comment: rot13(Va Nyrk Oryybf' jbeqf: Gur bqq bar bhg, vf gur bar gung vf abg gur bqq bar bhg.)

Comment: :00 but @melfnt the title remains unresolved LOL (is it a typo?)

Comment: As for the title: it is just... curious

Comment: @melfnt I'll take that as a yes to my question :P

Comment: So it's basically like the *"What is the smallest uninteresting number?"* question.

Comment: @darrel is this a question from PSE? Can you please share a link?

Comment: @melfnt No, it's just a reference to the [Interesting number paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interesting_number_paradox), which is basically that the smallest "uninteresting" number would be interesting, merely by virtue of being the smallest uninteresting number.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with these sort of puzzles is that there are many possible answers. A few possible ones include these.

Answer 1:

> B

Because:

> It is smaller than the others

Answer 2:

> A

Because:

> It is red

Answer 3:

> D

Because:

> It is not a fully written number

Answer 4:

> E

Because:

> There is no black within it

This is just the start of hundreds, if not thousands of possible answers. I don't know if it intentional but it may be a good idea to be a bit more specific in the type of differences that you are looking for.

Comment: I think your examples illustrate that @oAlt is onto something.

Comment: @Anon my point is that if you keep on digging, you will eventually find a reason that any of them is odd, tenfold!

Comment: Sooo which one of (a), (b), (c), (d) or (e) is the odd one out? XD

Comment: Well, as I say there are many different answers oAlt has a point well made, yes, but it is possible that the question is unanswerble